# Validate Models And User Input In Nancy

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nancy

What is the current method to validate Models in Nancy (Nancy FX?)?

Is it to roll my own, use DataAnnotations or for each class should I also implement an AbstractValidator?

I am attempting to validate many Models - my user registration page and regular model post pages. When using AbstractValidator; in my Module class do I call `.BindAndValidate<Foo>()` or `.Validate(fooInstance)`?

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9225316/model-validation-with-nancyfx) describes one method but its 3 years old so there may be newer ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one way to do validation i.e invoking `this.Validate(instance)`. `BindAndValidate<>()` does literally that i.e first it binds the model then it invokes Validate on it.

The Validate method will search for a validation factory which will create the actual validators for the model. I'm using fluent validation so in my case it invokes the defined validators.

I can't help you with data annotations since I don't use it, but with FluentValidation I just install the Nancy.Validation.FluentValidation package (nuget) and then I define the validators. That's it. I'm assuming a similar approach with data annotation.

Note that `.BindAndValidate()`  sets the validation result in `Context.ModelValidationResult` .